# ios 8/mobile-safari horizontal scrolling site with full screen sections and fixed header now breaking

Tags: iphone, twitter-bootstrap-3, ios8, mobile-safari

With some bootstrap 3.2 integration I have been making a horizontal scrolling site with 100% height and width divs to represent "pages".

It has been functioning correctly on various devices throughout development but when I went to use it in mobile-safari after ios 8 update the site is now displaying incorrectly...FFS

For the time being you can see the development site here:

(site is no longer active)

I'm pretty much convinced it is related to the audio/music player section. It's an old music player that has been restyled for the new site. The plan is for the site to go live with this player and then we'll be working on updating it after that.

To see how the site 'should' look you can view it in chrome on iphone (or on android of course).

It works fine in resized desktop browsers - it is literally just the ios 8 mobile-safari update that seems to have a bug.

For all I know they may update and it will fix itself, but I can't really just rely on that.

The navigation should be 100% of the viewport not 100% of the entire document.

There should be an audio player fixed at the bottom of the viewport.

I've tried a few things like stacking the divs vertically and while that helped with the navigation width issue it caused the audio player element then became contained within the parent 'music' container - I set the music container to overflow:scroll and -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch as with the other sections but the audio player controls stopped being fixed...? It also stopped it working in chrome for ios which means it really isn't a viable option.

(Please excuse the messy css if you do take a look. The feel of the music section was revised partway through and I'm waiting until the end of development to clean it up.)

As far as I can tell this is not something that has been asked yet - I've searched for a few hours but I think the case is probably quite unique (horizontal full page layouts with bespoke audio players are pretty uncommon as far as I know)

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: I get a FLASHBLOCK error "Failed to Start" I've never seen that before.  I can't do anything.

Comment: Hi Christina, would you be able to tell me what device/browser(s) are you using? Have you changed any of your default settings? That sounds like it is probably related to a flash nased html5 audio fallback.

Comment: Ok, what device is it? iphone 4,4s,5,5s etc?

Comment: Thank you.I'll need to take a look into that tomorrow.

Comment: There are weird problems with positioned: fixed in IOS 8 Safari. My own project was that I couldn't click a toggleClass until I scrolled a little bit. When I changed the postion to absolute, it worked, but then that screwed up the design, so my CSS is position absolute and when a user scrolls then it changes to position fixed, lucky for me this did the trick.

Comment: I've also got an issue with this same problem - fixed mobile nav is getting its width from something other than the viewport on ios 8. Will update here if I find a solution.

Comment: I have been working on another project and it has flagged something interesting to me. In the new project I have a sidebar menu that slides out from the left. It adds some absolutely positioned classes to other elements which causes the page width to increase. As this happens the fixed menu button is pushed off screen. So I'm sure there is some relation there, to the width of the page and use of absolutely positioned elements. I'm not sure exactly how they are related - the distance of displacement of the fixed elements isn't equal to distance of movement in the absolutely positioned elements.